# React Native "export default" not working after expo eject

Tags: react-native, babeljs, expo

I created an app with expo and everything worked fine.

Since I am now in need of native functionality I created a blank new app using react-native init and am trying to migrate my expo project to this new blank project to use the android and ios folder (exp detach didn't work for me).

However after migrating all files I am getting some weird errors when exporting components.

In the expo project I created components like this:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      //something
    ) 
  }
}
```

and then I used

```
import MyComponent from './~MyComponent'
```

to import it.

However after migrating I have to rewrite EVERY component like this to make it work:

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      //something
    )
  }
}

MyComponent = new myComponent
export default MyComponent
```

If I don’t do this, I get an Error of

```
"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined"
```

This is my setup:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "format": "prettier-eslint \"src/**/*.js\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^3.2.2",
    "mobx-react": "^4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.46.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.5.3",
    "prettier-eslint": "^6.4.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "eslint": "4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native",
    "react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ]
}
```

I guess it has something to do with my babel setup but I just can’t figure it out. Help would be very much appreciated since I have >100 components and rewriting all of them would be extremely tedious…

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, it worked after deinstalling all node modules, clearing the cache and reinstalling everything :)

Comment: I deleted my node modules folder, cleared my yarn cache, re installed, cleared my react-native and watchman cache, and I'm still getting this error. Any  suggestions? This is super frustrating

Answer (score 0):

**I have just ejected my project from Expo and I am facing quite the same situation mentioned in this question. 
So I leave my experience here hoping it may help others in future.**

The above uninstall&re-install method @phillipwinder mentioned doesn't work in my case.

After further searching and digging, I fffffinally solve it.
See below for details:

Error message:

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `ButtonFontIcon`.

After searching the error message, we know it means the import target component/method is not found, usually it's caused by misuse of export-import pair:

```
export default MyComponent
import MyComponent from 'xxx'
```

or

```
export MyComponent
import {MyComponent} from 'xxx'
```

so by intuition we are going to verify the `ButtonFontIcon` method which is mentioned in the error message. In this case, it's a custom component (below code is part of it).
However after verifying and testing other potential solutions again and again, the issue still remains.

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

export default function ButtonFontIcon({
    iconName, buttonStyle, size, onPress
}) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={onPress}
            underlayColor={buttonStyle === LIGHT_CONTENT ? colors.blackUnderlayOnBlack : colors.greyUnderlayOnWhite}
        >
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={size} style={{ color: (buttonStyle === LIGHT_CONTENT ? colors.whiteFontOnBlack : colors.blackDarkFontOnWhite) }} />
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight >
    );
}
```

In fact the issue is not caused by `ButtonFontIcon` itself. Instead, it's the `MaterialCommunityIcons` which is **inside** `ButtonFontIcon` causing problem.

**To sum up, the error message above sometimes won't show the exact error location, instead, all imported methods inside the indicated method should also be verified.**

In this case,

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
```

should be replaced by:

```
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
```

(And the original line before ejecting from Expo is:

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

)